# How to make time series chart's step larger in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, timeserieschart

I am developing a time series chart in Grafana. The chart gets data from Prometheus, which have a fetch interval of 1 minute. The problem is, when I set "step" value to Auto, the step in the chart is always 1 minute despite the time range is 1 day or 2 days. If possible, I would like the chart to have steps as followed (just an example, something similar but automatic is also very much appriciated):

- Less then 3 hours: 1 minute step
- From 3 hours to 12 hours: 10 minutes step
- More then 12 hours: 1 hour step

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do exactly like you described. But you can configure [Max data points](https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-max-number-of-data-points-for-display/75423): this will have similar result